# Blazor always shows dates in UTC format

Tags: c#, .net-core, webassembly, blazor

I'm currently working on some Blazor demos and samples and find out that in any supported browser it always displays date time and timezone in `UTC` format. My actual time zone is different from UTC.

Are there any restrictions in Blazor or WebAssembly? I'm using Blazor version 0.7.0 and there is a code snippet

```
@functions
{
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OS: {RuntimeInformation.OSDescription} {RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Processor: {RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Timezone is {TimeZoneInfo.Local}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Date time is {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Accroding to the [WebAssembly: Missing Timezone implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6368) GitHub issue, it's still an open issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue related to Mono Runtime when Blazor is run in Client Side. Is being tracked by [WebAssembly: Missing Timezone implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6368)

You can use this library as workaround [Toolbelt.Blazor.TimeZoneKit](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.TimeZoneKit)

Answer (score 3):

localisation isn't currently supported by mono. I've written a post (https://chrissainty.com/simple-localisation-in-blazor/) showing how you can implement localisation in your Blazor apps.

I've also published a nuget package [Blazored.Localisation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.Localisation/) if you just want to get on and not write things yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to show dates and times in your browsers local time check out the [Blazor Time](https://github.com/dustout/BlazorTime) library.

It introduces a `<ToLocal>` tag where you feed it a UTC or Server time and it will convert it to local.

```
<ToLocal DateTime="testUtcTime" Format="ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss"></ToLocal>
```